# "Your payment has been declined. Please try again." Magento 2.3.2

Tags: paypal, magento2, payment-gateway

Unable to place order using test credit card details on magento v2.3.2, below are the error log:

```js
'result' => 
  array (
    'result' => '1',
    'securetokenid' => 'x5u2GKhn3SsZbgIv1BCaYpwDtOYmRqjO',
    'respmsg' => 'User authentication failed',
    'result_code' => '1',
  ), 
``
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Honestly, this looks like an authentication issue, and you have not shown us how you tried to authenticate.  I assume the secure token ID was intended to be your “key,” but how did you get it, and so on?  That seems to be where the real question lies.  Pleae provide specifics (but no sensitive information!!!!)

Answer (score 0):

"User authentication failed" indicates Magento is configured with credentials that PayPal/Payflow do not accept.

Test your credentials at https://manager.paypal.com , and ensure the user account doesn't have a separate password for API operations. Create a new user if necessary, and wait up to 1 hour for it to be active.

Contact Payflow's support if you still have authentication problems.